# Show Table statement in Python script only reads in last row

Tags: python, teradata

I am trying to run a show table SQL statement within my Python script.  When I run this in Teradata it returns the full Show Table statement (columns, datatypes, unique index etc).

However, when I try to run this within the Python script itself:

```
def get_table_def():
    session = udaExec.connect(method="xxx", dsn="xxx", username="xxx", password="xxx");
    for row in session.execute("Show table TableABC"):
        print(row)

get_table_def()
```

it only returns the last row from the SQL statement, in this case:

```
UNIQUE_PRIMARY_IDX IDX1(ID)
```

I want it to return the full result, in this case the full CREATE TABLE statement generated from the SHOW TABLE statement.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: What API are you using? Please include all `import` lines. Is there a `cursor` available?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import re
import teradata
def get_table_def():
    lines = ''
    session = udaExec.connect(method="xxx", dsn="xxx", username="xxx", password="xxx");
    for row in session.execute("Show table TableABC"):
        for line in re.split('\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r', row[0]):
            lines+=line+'\n'
    print(lines)
    return lines

get_table_def()
```

This idea is explained in detailed here: http://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module?page=1